# How to connect to PPTP VPN from VBox Linux guest?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vpn, nat

My VBox guest is Ubuntu, and the network mode is NAT. **I cannot use Bridge Network mode.** I tried to connect to my VPN from the guest, but failed.

I can connect to the VPN on another VBox guest, which network is bridged. So I think the NAT mode is causing the problem. I think it is because I did not configure the `port-forwarding` rules correctly. But I have no idea which port the PPTP program uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PPTP is quite difficult to get to work.  It requires the use of Protocol 47 (not port 47) as well as TCP 1723.

You may want to look at using OpenVPN as an alternative.  It is simpler to set up (just UDP port 1194 or whatever you choose so it works really well with NAT - it can even be configured to work over TCP), and its more secure.